# JavaScript innerHTML trough form object

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that I wish to use more than one time in the same page. Is a upload form working with a javascript. The issue is how to display feedback messages in each form, can't use document.getElementById because the id will be the same, so I changed the name of the form and access the form elements by document.forms. But, as you see in the example below...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Label Changing: form approach</title>
<script>
function ini(){
    var form = document.forms["myForm"];
    document.getElementById("myLabel").innerHTML = "Usual Way Working";
    form.myLabel.innerHTML = "My Label Text";
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="ini();">
<form name="myForm">
    <label name="myLabel" id="myLabel"></label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the text "My Label Text" will not be displayed, it returns error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'form.myLabel.innerHTML = "My Label Text"'), and only "Usual Way Working" remains. Why? How can I write inside label trough form way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access any element in a form that way, only controls.

Had you written

```js
<form name="myForm">
    <input id="myInput">
```

then you could have accessed the input with `form.myInput`. But not labels or other elements.

You can write `form.getElementById('myLabel')` though.

Edit:
If you want to access any element by name rather than by ID, you can use the javascript [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) function. For your original example that would be

```
var label = document.querySelector('form[name="myForm"] label[name="myLabel"]');
label.innerHTML = "My Label Text";
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/kjG8c/).

Comment: The problem using id is when I duplicate de form in the same page, that I'll have two elements with the same id. I'm dealing by a naming methodology. That's sucks! With AS3 I duplicate objects easier...

Comment: You didn't state that in the question. Now in this case, it'd be best to use the querySelector function; see updated answer.

Comment: I did... whatever, it works. Thanks! Its a DOM3 method, but I'm not worry with compatibility this time. Maybe trough form.label work if converting the form element to DOM element, but I don't know how... it is possible?

Comment: No sure what you mean with converting to DOM element? Of course you can always get a list of labels in any form by writing `form.getElementsByTagName('label')` and then looping over the list to see which one you need. But I'm sure that was not what you meant.

Comment: When you use getElement, it means the result will be a DOM Element. But if you use forms["someForm"], the result is another kind of object (a "form Object") that hasn't all properties and methods of DOM Elements. In AS3 you can solve this by creating the type of object you need (if possible). Eg.: Button(SomeSimpleButton) result a Button object from a library that has more resources.

Comment: But a form object IS a dom element; it has all the properties a dom element has, and more.

Comment: As I shown above, innerHTML is a property that it doesn't have, so it's not the same object. Try my example. In Safari, "My Label Text" does not appears.

Comment: You haven't been paying attention. The text didn't appear because form.myLabel was not defined. not because a form object lacks `innerHTML`. Here is [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5EGpL/2/) that shows forms always have innerHTML, no matter if you access them by forms[..] or getElement... or create them from scratch. It also shows that all these objects are of type HTMLFormElement.

Comment: After so many testings, sometimes things got tricky... sometimes my local webserver trick me, I forgot that. I did the test again and now is working just like you said (the same html file). So I'll assume you're right and is the same kind of object. Thank you for been so patient with me!